# spring boot property with dashes

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot

Should the following application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.init-s-q-l
```

correctly bind to the object property

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource.initSQL
```

The key init-s-q-l is suggested by IntelliJ, yet it does not bind correctly.

The following *does* work:

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.initSQL
```

I thought this was an IntelliJ bug, so I created an issue:
[IDEA-160621](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-160621)

However, they seem to think it is a bug in spring boot. The bug report has an attached example project if it helps.
Thanks, Tom

Comment: Tom, I am working on the Spring Boot project and I confirm this seems to be a bug on our end. If we want to support relaxed binding, we have no other way to translate `SQL` to `s-q-l`. See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5330). Can you please create an issue in our tracker now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've raised a spring-boot issue for this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6803

Answer (score -1):

Seems this is the spring boot bug, in the metadata json file spring-configuration-metadata.json, it translate the configure properties to add "-" inline but not follow the camel case and cannot map it back.

```
{
  "name": "spring.datasource.tomcat.init-s-q-l",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "sourceType": "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
},
{
  "name": "spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size",
  "type": "java.lang.Integer",
  "sourceType": "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
}
```

Comment: Please see Stephane Nicoll's answer above for correct explanation.